# VueJs renders all elements upon a single change

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vue-component, virtual-dom

I have the following sample grid in which I push some new values to the bound list.

Press anywhere in the grid to push a new value to the grid.

As you can see in the fiddle, the updated cell will have a `green` color for 500 ms, and all the re-rendered elements will have `yellow` color.

The question is how we should configure `Vue` component so that it only re-render the changed element instead of them all?

If you look at the fiddle console output, you will see numbers like (13001, 26001, ...) and this equals to the number of all cells (1000 rows x 13 columns).

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pushed {
  background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue">
  var globalCount = 0;
</script>


<head>
  <title>Vue Render Performance</title>
</head>
<div id="demo">
  <demo-grid :data="gridData" :columns="gridColumns"> </demo-grid>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table @click="pushData()">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns">
          {{key}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(entry, i) in data">
        <td v-for="(key, j) in columns" :id="'a'+i +'_'+j">
          {{renderMe(entry[key], 'a'+i +'_'+j)}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>


<script>
  const data = newData(1000);
  var renderedCount = 0;
  var startTime = performance.now();

  Vue.component('demo-grid', {
    props: {
      data: Array,
      columns: Array,
      renderCount: Object,
    },
    template: '#grid-template',
    methods: {
      renderMe(el, id) {

        const elm = document.getElementById(id);
        if (elm) {
          elm.className += " yellow";
        }

        if (!renderedCount) {
          renderedCount = 0
        } else {
          renderedCount++;
        }

        return el;
      },
      pushData() {
        debugger
        var push = function() {
          let cols = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8", "Col9", "Col10", "Col11", "Col12", "Col13"];

          var t0 = performance.now();
          for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            let newVal = Math.random() * 10000,
              row = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000),
              cellIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols.length);
            cell = cols[cellIndex];
            if (data[row])
              data[row][cell] = newVal;

            var el = document.querySelector('tbody tr:nth-child(' + row + ') td:nth-child(' +
              cellIndex +
              ')');

            if (el) {
              el.className = 'pushed';

              el.scrollIntoView();

              var t = function() {
                if (el) {
                  el.className = '';
                }
                clearTimeout(t);
              };

              setTimeout(t, 500);
            }

            console.log('pushed  to cell [' + row + ',' + cellIndex + '] :' + newVal);
            console.log('Rendered Count: ' + renderedCount)
            renderedCount++;
          };
          var t1 = performance.now();
          console.log(t1 - t0)
        };

        push();
      }
    }
  });


  // bootstrap the demo
  var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
      searchQuery: '',
      gridColumns: ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8", "Col9", "Col10", "Col11", "Col12", "Col13"],
      gridData: data
    }
  })

  Vue.config.devtools = true;

  function newData(count) {
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      data.push({
        Col1: "Record",
        Col2: 818959475,
        Col3: 467587749,
        Col4: 438,
        Col5: 439,
        Col6: 440,
        Col7: 2.1,
        Col8: 436.2,
        Col9: 2.4,
        Col10: 5770,
        Col11: 5771,
        Col12: 5772,
        Col13: 5773
      });
    }

    return data;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using Vue's [reactivity](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) to render your data

Comment: @Phil, you mean `Vue.set` ?

Comment: Not only that. Your component has no `data`. Instead, it manipulates a globally declared variable as well as directly manipulating the DOM. At the very least, it should emit the click event up to the parent Vue instance and that should make the changes to its data using `Vue.set`

Comment: @Phil, I removed the global object but yet I get the same result, I couldn't access data (props) inside functions defined in `methods` so I passed them via child component. https://jsfiddle.net/mafshin/2jyyr0md/

Answer (score 4):

When you don't want to re-render and entire list of information, the typical way to handle it is to push the things that need to re-render into a component. Here is an updated version of your code that pushes the rows into a component and renders a fraction of what you were doing before.

```
Vue.component("demo-row", {
  props:["entry", "columns", "rowIndex"],
    template:`
        <tr>
            <td v-for="(key, j) in columns" :id="'a'+rowIndex +'_'+j">
                {{renderMe(entry[key], 'a'+rowIndex +'_'+j)}}
            </td>
        </tr>  
  `,
  methods:{
    renderMe(el, id) {

      const elm = document.getElementById(id);
      if (elm) {
        elm.className += " yellow";
      }

      if (!renderedCount) {
        renderedCount = 0
      } else {
        renderedCount++;
      }

      return el;
    },
    }
})

Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  props: {
    items: Array,
    columns: Array
  },
  template: '#grid-template',
  methods: {
    pushData() {
      this.$parent.pushData(this.$parent.gridItems, this.$parent.gridColumns);
    }
  }
});
```

[Example codepen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xLEEjd?editors=1010).

Note, I did not change anything else that you are doing that could probably be done more idiomatically in Vue, I just wanted to demonstrate that there is no need for *everything* to re-render.